# Relation between semiring structure of natural numbers and their hereditarily finite sets structure under bitwise operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, lattice-orders, semiring

**Some background**

The natural numbers $\mathsf{Nat}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ has the structure of a semiring under addition and multiplication.

Write $\mathsf{HFS}$ for the set of all [hereditarily finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set) (the inductively defined collection of all sets that are finite and all of whose elements are hereditarily finite).

$\mathsf{Nat}$ bijects with $\mathsf{HFS}$ under the [Ackermann coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set#Ackermann_coding) $ack:\mathsf{Nat}\to\mathsf{HFS}$, which maps $n\in Nat$ to
$$
ack(n)=\{ack(i) \mid BIT(n,i)\}, 
$$
where $BIT(n,i)$ is the [BIT predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIT_predicate), which is true precisely when the $i$th bit of the binary representation of $n$ is $1$.

This trivially gives the numbers $\mathsf{Nat}$ the structure of a lattice, where for example
$$
n\vee n' = ack^{-1}(ack(n)\cup ack(n')).
$$

*(Note that this simple-seeming construction can do a lot.  For example as Wikipedia notes with can use it to [construct the Rado graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIT_predicate#Construction_of_the_Rado_graph).  I also remember reading somewhere that every nonstandard model of natural numbers gives rise to a model of ZF set theory, via $ack$.)*

**My question**

The correspondence runs the other way too: $\mathsf{HFS}$ inherits a semiring structure from $\mathsf{Nat}$, via $ack$.  But this invites us to ask:

1. What is known about this structure?
2. In more detail: what is known about the interaction between the semiring structure of $\mathsf{Nat}$ and its lattice structure via $ack$?
3. Does a theory of "set-like semirings" exist: lattice-ordered semirings which are algebraic structures with the structure of semirings *and* lattices, along with axioms on the behaviour of $n\vee (n' + n'')$; as there are axioms on the behaviour of $n * (n' + n'')$ and $n \wedge (n' \vee n'')$?  *(I'm not particular about semirings and lattices; e.g. if some kind of bounded NAND operation is more natural than AND and OR, then that's fine too.  What I care about is mixing the arithmetic structure with the natural bitwise/HFS sets structure in some sensible abstraction, above and beyond the bare fact of the definitions as noted above.)*
4. If no such algebra exists, why *shouldn't* it exist?  What is the underlying barrier to constructing it?

Thank you.

Comment: ...The natural numbers do not have a ring structure w.r.t. the usual addition and multiplication. There are no additive inverses. And so $\mathsf{HFS}$ does not inherit a ring structure from $\Bbb{N}$ through the Ackermann encoding.

Comment: Thank you @Servaes.  My error.  Edited "ring" to "semiring".